# Update UI in coroutine after Activity.onDestroy()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have this code in my activity:

```
private val job = Job()
private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

    ioScope.launch {
        delay(3000L)
        textView.text = "test1"
        uiScope.launch {
            textView.text = "test2"
        }
    }
}
```

If I launch and wait 3 seconds app will crash with `CalledFromWrongThreadException` which is predictable cause I update Ui from background thread in line `textView.text = "test1"`.

But if I press back button I see that onPause() and onDestroy() will be called, but both lines `textView.text = "test1"` in background thread and `textView.text = "test1"` in UI thread will be called, but without exception.

Why it does not crash, cause I update UI on destroyed activity?

Is it safe to write code in such way? For example, do a network call and update UI after response(when Activity could be destroyed), or there could be some issues?

Comment: Usually, when Activity is destroyed we call `uiScope.cancel()` in `onDestroy()` method to stop coroutine's job.

Comment: @Sergey yes I saw it, but what happens if dont call?

Comment: I guess coroutine will continue to work.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically causing a (temporary) memory leak by not cancelling the coroutine. Updating a View after the Activity is destroyed will not actually cause any exception to be thrown; rather, the changes just won't be reflected in any UI. You're updating values in an Activity that has been discarded, but only kept in memory due to your coroutine keeping a reference to it.

As @Sergey mentions, you should `job.cancel()` in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Does I understand correct: if I write code in such way no issues will appears, and Activity will be released after coroutine ends?
So, generally speaking, it's acceptable to launch coroutine for short-term operations like internet/database request without cancel it onDestroy?

Comment: No, you definitely want to clean up after the activity is destroyed. If not only for the memory implications, there are some things you can do in an Activity after it's destroyed that *will* cause a crash, and these issues will be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: "Updating a View after the Activity is destroyed will not actually cause any exception to be thrown" How about KotlinNullPointerException when referencing the dead view?

Comment: It won't be null unless you set it to null explicitly. And if it's nullable, you'd have to be using an unsafe `view!!` to cause an NPE anyway.